# <div> tag with clickable link with <a> tag inside

Tags: javascript, css, html

So I m using a  tag with a whole block used as a link, it is a product display so you click it it goes to product page. Now on in that  I created an  tag as a button for a link to the cart page. So I have it working, but when i click the CART button both pages open the product and the cart. I know its doing that because the cart button is within the block that is a link. I did 2 versions and they both don't work!
But how do I fix it ??

version1:

```
 <Div class="col-md-3" onClick="window.open('product.html');"  >
    <Div class="product-thumb">
      <h4>MacBook</h4>
      <img src="image/macbook_1-200x200.jpg" alt="Product">
      <p>Intel Core 2 Duo processor Powered by an Intel Core 2 Duo processor at speeds up to 2.1..</p>
      <p class="price">$3000 USD</p>
      <a href="cart.html;" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart</a> 
  </Div>
```

Version2:

```
<Div class="col-md-3" onClick="window.open('product.html');"  >
    <Div class="product-thumb">
      <h4>MacBook</h4>
      <img src="image/macbook_1-200x200.jpg" alt="Product">
      <p>Intel Core 2 Duo processor Powered by an Intel Core 2 Duo processor at speeds up to 2.1..</p>
      <p class="price">$3000 USD</p>
      <a href="cart.html" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart</a> </Div>
  </Div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: yes i m using bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

You can use stopPropagation. Without seeing your code can’t be 100% sure but something like this:

```
$(a).click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: basically we can use this but just adding it as a { onClick="event.stopPropagation()" } works too

Answer (score 1):

It's because of [event bubbling](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/), you need to use `event.stopPropagation()` to avoid this behaviour.

```
    <Div class="col-md-3" onClick="window.open('product.html');">
      <Div class="product-thumb">
        <h4>MacBook</h4>
        <img src="image/macbook_1-200x200.jpg" alt="Product">
        <p>Intel Core 2 Duo processor Powered by an Intel Core 2 Duo processor at speeds up to 2.1..</p>
        <p class="price">$3000 USD</p>
        <a href="cart.html" onClick="event.stopPropagation()" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart</a> </Div>
    </Div>
```

Comment: this works Perfectly right now, i dont know if it will create in the future if i add features to the website but for now as a template it works perfect. no need to add any scripts.

Comment: @SaadiSLM glad it worked :) It should work anyways as long as your nested `a` tags uses `event.stopPropagation()`. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `onclick` and the `location.href` and by passsing link inside this,

```
<div onclick="location.href='your_url'">
 ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the event from bubbling up the DOM tree with `event.stopPropagation()`.

```html
<div class="col-md-3" onClick="window.open('product.html');"  >
    <div class="product-thumb">
      <h4>MacBook</h4>
      <img src="image/macbook_1-200x200.jpg" alt="Product">
      <p>Intel Core 2 Duo processor Powered by an Intel Core 2 Duo processor at speeds up to 2.1..</p>
      <p class="price">$3000 USD</p>
      <a href="cart.html" id="cartlink" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart</a> </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  document.getElementById("cartlink").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  </script>
```